# Java: JAI vs. JIMI

Tags: java, image, image-loading

I'm using JAI for loading image formats that aren't supported by ImageIO (e.g. CUR, TIFF, etc). I've never gave a try for JIMI, because it seems to use natives (and I should not use JNI-based libraries, since I'm making something *full cross-OS*), and it seems to be a 'image-manipulator', and not a 'image-loader' (which is what I'm wanting), even that it can load images, but I don't need any image manipulators.

So, for an application that I'm making *full cross-OS* as most possible, should I use JAI or JIMI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, both JAI and JIMI are cross-platform, but JIMI is very old, and JAI is not so easy to use...

I would consider the Apache [Imaging](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/formatsupport.html) project (formerly known as Sanselan). As you can see from the linked page, it supports TIFF and ICO, which is [practically the same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) as CUR.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna take a look on that.